# Displaying information about SolR search result

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am struggling with a little problem where I have to display relevant information about the resultset returned from SolR but can't figure out how to calculate it without iterating the results (bad).

Basically I am storing my documents with a `state` field and while the search is supposed to return all documents, the UI has to show **"Found 15 entities, 5 are in state A, 3 in state B and 8 in C"**.

At the moment I am using a rather brittle approach of running the query 3 times with additional scoping by type, but I'd rather get that information from the one query I am displaying. (There have been some edge cases where the numbers don't add up and since SolR can return facets I guess there has to be a way to use that functionality in this case)

I am using SolR 3.5 from Rails with the [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.io/) gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention yourself, you can use facets for this by setting

```
facet=true&facet.field=state
```

I'm not familiar with the sunspot gem, but by looking at the [documentation](http://sunspot.github.io/) you can use
facets like this(Assuming Entity is your searchable):

```
Entity.search do:
  facet :state
end
```

This should return the states of all entities returned by your query with the number of entities in this state. The Sunspot [documentation](http://sunspot.github.io/docs/index.html#Faceting) tells me you can read these facets in the following way:

```
search.facet(:state).rows.each do |facet|
  puts "State #{facet.value} has #{facet.count} entities"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially there are three main sets of functions you can use to garner stats from solr.

The first is faceting:
 
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters

There is also grouping (field collapsing):
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

And the stats package:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component

Although the stats, facet and group may be replaced by the analytic package known as olap which is aimed to be in solr V 5.0.0: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5302

Good luck.